# There was an error during installation: Extension is invalid - Adapting chrome extension into firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, firefox, odoo

I'm adapting a google-chrome extension into firefox.

This extension is fairly simple, it just reloads current browser window and places a specific string into it (It is used to activate a debugging state on `Odoo`).

However, when I test it agaisnt the mozilla test site, it says the test has passed and the extension should be ready to go.

But everytime I try on my browser on `about:debugging` erss, it throws the same thing over and over again.

Just updated the browser to version `57.0` and the same story goes on.

This is my directory structure (I've added the addon to a zip file)

```
 background.js
 LICENSE
 manifest.json
 off.png
 on.png
 README.md
 super_on.png
```

My manifest file:

```
{
"name": "My Debug",
"version": "3.3",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Toggle debug mode",
"short_name": "My Debug",
"offline_enabled": true,
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "off_.png",
    "default_title": "- Click for Debug \n- Double Click for Debug"
},
"applications": {
      "id": "email@email.com"
},
"incognito": "spanning",
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"permissions": ["activeTab", "webNavigation", "*://*/*", "tabs"],
"icons": {
    "16": "off.png",
    "128": "off.png"
}
}
```

It throws me:

```
There was an error during installation: Extension is invalid
```

I know the `install.rdf` isn't needed anymore.

Maybe some error on manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a chrome or firefox extension to activate and set the debug mode by default in Odoo. You can do something like the following code withing the Odoo framework. This is taken from [this Odoo module](https://github.com/sotogarcia/odoo-development/blob/master/modules/development_tools/controllers/web_main.py)

- Create a class with the settings values

  ```py
  class DevelopmentToolsConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):

      _name = 'development_tools.config.settings'

      development_mode = fields.Boolean(
          string='Development mode as default',
          required=False,
          readonly=False,
          index=False,
          default=True,
          help='Set development mode by default'
      )

      @api.model
      def get_default_values(self, values):
          return dict(
              development_mode=self.get_debug_mode(),
          )            

      def get_debug_mode(self):
          param = self._get_parameter('development_mode')

          if param:
              value = self._safe_eval(param.value, bool)
          else:
              value = self._defaults['development_mode']

          return value

      def _set_debug_mode(self):
          param = self._get_parameter('development_mode', force=True)
          param.value = unicode(self.development_mode)
  ```
- Override `web.Home` controller and add auto-debug mode behavior:

  ```py
  from openerp.http import route, request, Controller, redirect_with_hash
  import openerp.addons.web.controllers.main as webmain
  from openerp.tools.translate import _
  from logging import getLogger
  import werkzeug

  _logger = getLogger(__name__)


  class Home(webmain.Home):

      @route()
      def web_client(self, s_action=None, **kw):
          result = None

          if not request.debug and request.db and self._get_debug_mode():
              _logger.info(self._debug_message)
              result = self._build_debug_response()

          return result or super(Home, self).web_client(s_action, **kw)

      def _get_debug_mode(self):
          config = request.env['development_tools.config.settings']
          debug = config.get_debug_mode()

          return debug == True

      def _build_debug_response(self):
          result = None

          try:
              query = request.params
              query.update({'debug': u''})
              url = '/web?' + werkzeug.url_encode(query)
              result = redirect_with_hash(url)
          except Exception as ex:
              _logger.error(self._error_response.format(ex))

          return result

      _debug_message = _(u'Auto-redirect to enter in debug mode')

      _error_response = _(
          u'The debug response could not be built.\n'
          u'System has said: {}'
      )
  ```